# What is the best way to do a wizard form in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a form with multi steps to order goods like a wizard form...

1) I can code it in one view through the tab-pane, but how can i validate each tab before moving to the next one.

2) Someone gave me some advice to make this according to "actionCreate", but after successful saving make a redirect to the next step of filling the step, but then there will be extra 2-3 tables and models ... but it is working, see the example below:

```
public function actionShipping($id)
{
    $model = new OrderDeliveryMethod();
    $model->order_id = $id;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['payment', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('shipping', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionPayment($id)
{
    $model = new OrderPaymentMethod();
    $model->order_id = $id;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['review', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('payment', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionReview($id)
{
    return $this->render('review', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

**Is there another way to  to do that? Can you give me an example?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store everything in one table, in one model but changing your scenario to i.e. `step1, step2, step3..`.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_STEP1 = 'step1';
    const SCENARIO_STEP2 = 'step2';
    ...

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_STEP1 => ['attr1', 'attr2'],
            self::SCENARIO_STEP2 => ['attr3', 'attr4', 'attr5'],
        ];
    }
    ...
```

So that in first step you will create a Wizard Model, and set its Scenario (in order to validate and save attributes chosen only for step-1)

```
public function actionStep1()
{
    $model = new OrderWizard();
    $model->setScenario(OrderWizard::SCENARIO_STEP1);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['step-2', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('step-1', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then in Step 2 you fetch the previously created model and continue filling and validating its attrubtes, like:
public function actionStep1()

```
public function actionStep2($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->setScenario(OrderWizard::SCENARIO_STEP2);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    ...
```

..But the given method (mine and yours) has a drawback, so that if client finishes the first step, but then abandones the sequence, your table will be filled with lots of unfinished data.
Therefore instead of redirecting to multiple actions, you can implement Wizard in single page with JS hide/show attributes logic. Individual form fields can be validated using:

```
$('#contact-form').yiiActiveForm('validateAttribute', 'contactform-name');
```

And the whole form:

```
$('#contact-form').yiiActiveForm('validate', true);
```

You can get more information from the following link: [Working with ActiveForm via JavaScript](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/)

About hiding and showing attributes in each step, I am not sure whether hidden attributes are validated, but 'disabled' ones are skipped for sure.. I hope you get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: Oh thanks, I think that using scenarios is a very good way to solve this problem. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Although it is an old question and answered already but, for future references if anyone wants to create a form wizard I wanted to add my answer as I have created a [yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) which create a form wizard using the `ActiveForm` and `Models`.

### Prominent Features

- You can use a single model across all steps.
- Single model dedicated to every step.
- Multiple models to a single step.
- Disable/Enable validation.
- Customize & order form fields.
- Tabular Steps with <kbd>Add Row</kbd> button to add fields dynamically like Adress book.
- Form Persistence (saves the un-saved form to be restored later using `localstorage`).
- Preview Step ( Previews all the form input with labels as the last step, and navigates to the step when clicked).
- Multiple Themes

### Demos

You can see the [DEMOS](http://yii2plugins.idowstech.com/formwizard/index) with all available variations.

### SETUP

use composer to install the extension

`php composer.phar require  buttflattery/yii2-formwizard "@dev"`

or add into the composer.json file under require section

`"buttflattery/yii2-formwizard":"@dev"`

### Sample Code

```
use buttflattery\formwizard\FormWizard;

$shootsModel=new Shoots();
$shootTagModel= new ShootTag();

echo FormWizard::widget([
    'steps'=>[
        [
            'model'=>$shootsModel,
            'title'=>'My Shoots',
            'description'=>'Add your shoots',
            'formInfoText'=>'Fill all fields'
        ],
        [
            'model'=> $shootTagModel,
            'title'=>'My Shoots',
            'description'=>'Add your shoots',
            'formInfoText'=>'Fill all fields'
        ],
    ]
]);
```